# Is creating page contents dynamically using javascript faster than loading different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm designing a website with different pages and every page has it's contents as like as `textbox, label, button, gridview` and etc.
after that I want to load every pages using `$("#xx").load(page url Address)` in jquery to prevent postback when the page is necessary.

is this method faster or following method:

I have just one page for example: `default.aspx` and a `javascript` file.
The page contents will be created using javascript dynamically just in one page  with `createElement` instead of loading different pages.

In the first method all `aspx` elements should be converted to `html` and then html elements must be transferred to the client but in the second method we won't have any `html` element transferring except for the `default.aspx` page and the elements will create in run-time using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Alexandre in that I would prefer the first approach.

By going with a load on demand type of approach for different parts of your application, you can carve up your app into logical pieces and load them only when necessary.  Also, with this approach, you'll probably have less data being transferred to and from the server and shift a bit of the processing to the client.

With the second approach, it sounds like you'll end up with a rat's nest of code about what button or link was clicked and then routing the call to various event handlers or other methods.  You'll centralize most of your logic (since everything is done on the client), but I think it will become overly complex faster than the first approach.

If you go with the first approach, and if you end up with a great deal of JavaScript, I would recommend the following:

1. Make sure you organize your JavaScript logically and not pollute the
   global namespace.  Create objects/functions for each chunk that
   you're loading and try to contain that JavaScript functionality
   within that particular chunk's JavaScript function/object.
2. Run JSLint often on your JavaScript.  VS2010 has a nice JSLint add-in that will run JSLint every time you save or build or on-demand.

Good luck!  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is much better, because you are charging portions of the page when you need them.

It will require a refresh of some portions but will take a lot of heavy height from the client.

In the second method you rely a lot of processing on the client (browser), and that can create bottlenecks related with bandwidth and client processing.

Comment: I'm suggesting the second method to prevent botlenecks related with bandwidth. because the transfering data between server and client will be decreased. am I in wrong?